# Get the loaded instance of the code behind of ResourceDictionary

Tags: code-behind, resourcedictionary

I've made a resource dictionayry for a user control and create a class that derived from ResourceDictionary that managed different eventsetters and handlers for controls contained in the resource dictionary. So far so good, everything is working fine. My problem is to access members contained in my ResourceDictionary class from the user control. How to access a property in ResouceDictionary object from the user control?

Thanks a lot!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a way to handle it. I create a variable of my resourcedictionary type that handle also his events. After, I set the resource dictionary to the control by code with my variable. So now, I can handle events declared in my resource dictionary.

If someone need to see codes needed to get the job done, let me know.